# Constructing a map without fixed point on an acyclic space

Tags: general-topology, continuity, fixed-points

This is an exercise given in order to show that all the hypothesis in the Lefschetz theorem are indeed essential. So I'm given the following three subsets of $\mathbb R ^3$:
$$A = \{(x,y,0); x^2 + y^2 = 1\},$$
$$B = \{(x,0,z); (x-1)^2 + z^2 = 1, z \geq 0 \},$$
$$C = \{\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)(\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t), 0); t \in [1, \infty)\},$$

that is, $A$ is a disk in the $xy$ plane, $B$ is a semicircle in the $xz$ plane with center in $(1,0)$ and $C$ is a spiral in the $xy$ plane accumulating on the border of $A$. I've already shown that the space $X = A \cup B \cup C$ is compact and acyclic, now I've been asked to construct a continuous map $f: X \to X$ without fixed points, but every time I think of something it ends up not being continuous. Can anyone think of one such map? I believe this is an exercise from Bredon's Topology and Geometry, by the way.

Comment: In set $C$ do we assume $t$ ranges over some interval excluding $0,$ maybe $(0,1]$?

Comment: Yeah, $t$ ranges from $1$ to $\infty$. I'll fix that.

Comment: Here's an idea: rotate both $A$ and $B$ via some small fixed angle. Rotate $A$ clockwise. Then you reparametrize $C$ so that near $A$ it rotates just as $A$ while near $B$ it is stretched and goes into $B$ (so that continuity at the point of contact between $B$ and $C$ holds). In other words if you rotate $A$ by $\alpha$ then you reparametrize $C$ via $t:=t-\alpha$. What is left is mapped to $B$.

Comment: @freakish If $B$ is rotated by a fixed small angle, won't there be a point near one end of the semicircle that rotates outside the semicircle?

Comment: If $A$ is a *disk* then, I guess, $A = \{(x,y,0); x^2 + y^2 \le 1\}$.